# AWS EMR using PySpark to connect Mysql but return "requirement failed: The driver could not open a JDBC connection"

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm running a Spark application on AWS EMR. I try to connect to MySQL database using Spark SQL like this:

```
with SparkSession.builder.appName('My test spark').getOrCreate() as spark:
    dataframe_mysql = spark.read.format('jdbc').options(
        url='mydb.host.com',
        driver='com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver',
        dbtable='mydb.my_table',
        user='username',
        password='password',
        isolationLevel='NONE'
    ).load()
```

But AWS EMR always failed with this:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The driver could not open a JDBC connection. Check the URL: mydb.host.com
```

I've also tried different formats of the `url` arg according to documents I found:

```
jdbc:mysql:mydb.host.com
jdbc:mysql://mydb.host.com
mydb.host.com
```

But they all failed with same infomation. And this code could successfully connected to MySQL in my local Spark cluster. What's the right way to connect to MySQL in AWS EMR? Or how could I get more specifically failed info?

Comment: based on this , you need to check your VPCs for EMR & Redshift , they might be hosted in different VPC(s) , if thats the case , you would need to establish VPC peering for apps hosted to communicate to each other

Comment: @Vaebhav i've try to connect database using sqlalchemy, and it works. So I think that's a problem of my code. And I've tried out the right way. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer, the right format of arg `url` is `jdbc:mysql://mydb.host.com/mydb`

I'm using emr-6.6.0 and mysql-connector-java-8.0.29, I found many different claims about this, and really made me delusive. Maby because different version had different usage?